# How does Visual C++ IDE create (relatively) small DLL's

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I compiled the following code into a DLL in visual C++ with the "release" configuration

```
#define MY_FIRST_DLL __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" MY_FIRST_DLL
int main(void)
{
   return 0;
}
```

And the size of the DLL was 7 KB.

I created a file called `test.cpp` and compiled it manually in command-line with the following:

```
cl /LD test.cpp
```

And it was 32 KB.

What does the IDE do that allows it to create the 7 KB dll from the same code?
And how can I achieve the same result manually (or perhaps a batch file)?

Comment: Putting `main` in a DLL is rather weird.

Comment: It used to be called `test` but then I randomly changed the name and happened to pick `main` for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the 'release' option, the command line to build your code is very different. Visual Studio sets the optimizations settings and other thinks.
You can see that command line, in the project configurations: -> C/C++ compiler ( or something like this ) -> command line ( option )

see the picture:
[image]

Comment: I'm unable to find the command-line that is used during a release build. Where is the "project configurations" menu? I am using the express edition if it makes a difference.

Comment: a Right-click on your project, proprieties-> C/C++ -> Command Line ... in this screen, you will see all the command line options used with Visual Studio...

Comment: Alright I found it :) Some things I ran into along the way: if you don't have any source files (eg: blank project), the C/C++ node does not appear. If you right-click and hit properties on the Solution, none of those nodes appear either.